# Android repeat action inside other action repeating

Tags: android

Sorry for my English! :)

Ok, I want to repeat something multiple times every second - like here:

```
    //Declare the timer
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Called each time when 1000 milliseconds (1 second) (the period parameter)
    }

},
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
1000);
```

Now, inside it I want to generate random number between 1-3 (including) and do something if it is 3.

So:

```
    //Declare the timer
Timer t = new Timer();
//Set the schedule function and rate
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int num = rand.nextInt(3)+1;
        if(num==3){
        // repeat action here.
        }
    }

},
//Set how long before to start calling the TimerTask (in milliseconds)
0,
//Set the amount of time between each execution (in milliseconds)
1000);
```

And inside the if statement, I want to repeat other action (moving ImageView every 5 milliseconds or something like this). How can I do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either a CountDownTimer 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html
e.g. create a CountDownTimer for 30secs (30000ms) and notify each second (1000ms)

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //I get called every 1000ms
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
 }.start();
```

or just a Handler.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

       //dostuff
       handler.postDelayed(this,1000); //repeat after a second

    }
});
```

For animations you should have a look at ObjectAnimator/ViewPropertyAnimation.